# openssh exit status codes and their meaning

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to find OpenSSH exit status codes and their meaning but I can't find it anywhere. I'm sure it will be of helpful for others.

Mainly I'm interested in `Exit status 5` because I get that as soon as authentication is successful on Windows server 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that you are referring to client command.

As the **man** page says[1], `ssh` exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.

> **EXIT STATUS**
>
> **ssh** exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error occurred.

If it's returning `Exit status 5` it's because your remote command it's returning that status code, perhaps the default shell of the user might be returning that.

That being said, if you take a look at the Windows System Error Codes[2][3], you will see that there is an error code `5` and it's related to `Access is denied` error:

> **ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED**
>
> 5 (0x5)
>
> Access is denied.

So **maybe** you don't have Windows permissions to run the remote command (or default user shell/command) you are trying to.

References:

- [1] https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#EXIT_STATUS
- [2] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx
- [3] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx

Comment: There was no remote command though, just after authentication is successful, it exits. I was able to resolve that with openssh reinstall

Comment: @anon probably that openssh reinstall fixed some permission issue.

Comment: @anon What openssh reinstall? The server side or the client side?